# How does `aws_global` in the config file work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

In [the `~/.aws/config` documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html#cli-configure-files-global), the `region` section has this note:

> `aws_global` enables you to specify the global endpoint for services that support a global endpoint in addition to Regional endpoints, such as AWS Security Token Service (AWS STS) and Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3).

It's not clear to me how this works.  What would the config look like for specifying some global endpoint URLs here?

Comment: Typically, you would have no need to modify any of the Endpoints. I normally see it used when people are using AWS-compatible services, such as Minio, and they need to send the API commands to a service different to AWS.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I'm in such a situation - call it "somebody didn't pay attention and misconfigured".